# Google Play Services: Cloud Save

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I'm implementing cloud save to my Unity game using [offical plugin](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity)

after calling: `((PlayGamesPlatform)Social.Active).SavedGame.OpenWithAutomaticConflictResolution(Application.persistentDataPath + "/cloudsave", DataSource.ReadCacheOrNetwork, ConflictResolutionStrategy.UseLongestPlaytime, SaveGameOpened);`

I get following warning:

```
***[Play Games Plugin DLL]... ERROR: Received invalid filename: /storage.emulated/0/Android/data/com.blabla.bla/files/cloudsave
```

The file at this location is created, but empty.

How I can track this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything I changed was the path from: `Application.persistentDataPath + "/cloudsave"` to `"cloudsave"` and it works.

I was trying to do this before, but there had to be some similar error in other part of code.